# Facing error both DataSource and And DataSourceID are defined on GridView Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, gridview, datasource

i am using entity frame work and want to bind data on Grid View but facing problem i have code that i am pasting as well as attaching screen shot i also saw answer regarding this problem but not beneficial for me so any one have experience with this error must be appreciated.

[image]

aspx.cs Code

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            BindGrid();
        }
        lblMessage.Text = "";
    }

    void BindGrid()
    {
        using (GapEntities1 context = new GapEntities1())
        {
            if (context.Organizations.Count() > 0)
            {
                // GdvOrganization is a gridview ID name
                GdvOrganization.DataSource = context.Organizations;
                GdvOrganization.DataBind();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like you are trying to bind the GridView from Markup side (.aspx ) as well as using code behind.( .aspx.cs )

Choose any one way only to bind the grid.

1.) If you bind gridview from code behind then remove the `DataSourceId` property from grid view from markup. Change below code:

```
<asp:gridview id="GdvOrganization" runat="server" autogeneratecolumns="False" 
DataSourceID="MyDataSource">
```

to

```
<asp:gridview id="GdvOrganization" runat="server" autogeneratecolumns="False">
```

2.) if you prefer to bind from markup side then you have to remove the c# code to bind the grid.

Still if above 2 steps doesn't interest you, try below trick ( Recommended ?? )

```
GdvOrganization.DataSource = ds;
GdvOrganization.DataSourceID = String.Empty;
GdvOrganization.DataBind();
```