# How change data grid view datasource with ObjectDataSource?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have two ObjectDataSources in my form.i want change data grid view datasource with ObjectDataSources.

Button's eventhandler to change ObjectDataSource1 is :

```
protected void lbnChangeInfo1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    gdvList.DataSource = null;
    gdvList.DataBind();
    gdvList.DataSource = odsWork1;
    gdvList.DataBind();
}
```

Button's eventhandler to change ObjectDataSource2 is :

```
protected void lbnChangeInfo2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    gdvList.DataSource = null;
    gdvList.DataBind();
    gdvList.DataSource = odsWork2;
    gdvList.DataBind();
}
```

When executed, this error is thrown:

> Additional information: Both DataSource and DataSourceID are defined
>   on 'gdvList'.  Remove one definition.

Comment: Possible to duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10208249/both-datasource-and-datasourceid-are-defined-on-gridview1-remove-one-definiti

Comment: Possible to duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22248048/facing-error-both-datasource-and-and-datasourceid-are-defined-on-gridview-entity

Comment: i do it but not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change code with :

```
protected void lbnChangeInfo1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   gdvList.DataSource = null;
   gdvList.DataSourceID = null;
   gdvList.DataSource = odsWork1;
   gdvList.DataBind();
}
```